# Errors after upgrading to forge viewer version 7.55

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

we are experiencing errors in the latest version (7.55) of the forge viewer. When loading a Revit model, the following error displays in the browser console:

```
Failed to load model: New Construction. Error code: TypeError: e.target.clone is not a function
```

[image: viewer error]

This is an SVF2 model that was translated using the `generateMasterViews` flag. New Construction is one of the master views names in this particular model.

I had a hunch this was due to the new update, so I downgraded our version from 7.55 to 7.54. After downgrading the issue no longer occurred. Was there a breaking change in 7.55 that we need to be aware of? I did not see anything in the [changelog](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#id1)

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer uses [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org) so none of the "minor" version updates should be breaking, but it could be some regression. In the call stack I see you're using `AggregatedView`. Have you tried loading your model in a simple `Viewer3D` or `GuiViewer3D` instance instead of that one? And could you share more details about how you're initializing the viewer and loading the models into it?